# How to use application path in c# app from resources and other folder too

Tags: c#, path

I am making an app where I am putting some MP3 files into one single folder you may see the link of  picture of that directory below  ↓

[image]

now I took one windows media player tool from toolbox and I am writing this code over one button.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "C:\\Users\\Windows\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2012\\Projects\\FreshAbc\\FreshAbc\\dreammusic\\DrmMTrack8.lite.mp3";
}
```

but when i am publishing it and running in other pc its showing me a message that directory missing and blah blah so my simple question is is there any way to write this code like this so that if i give TO somebody the publish version he can use :-

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "\\dreammusic\\DrmMTrack8.lite.mp3";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection for this:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var AssemblyPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = Path.Combine(AssemblyPath, "dreammusic\\DrmMTrack8.lite.mp3");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that all of your mp3's "Copy To Output Directory" property are set to be copied to the output folder. Click on each MP3 one by one and in the "Properties" tab set to "Copy Always" or "Copy If Newer":

[image: Set to Copy To Output folder]

Then you can set your URL accordingly:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = @"dreammusic\DrmMTrack8.lite.mp3";
}
```

When you deploy your app now, it will be deployed with the MP3 files and the URL will work.

Answer (score 0):

If these files are stored inside one of the "special folders" (like `My Documents`, or `AppData/Roaming`), the simplest way would be to use `Environment.GetFolderPath` with `Environment.SpecialFolder`. I.e. calling `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments))` would return something like `C:\Users\(some user)\Documents\` on post XP machines.

If actually depends on how you are deploying the files. If they are deployed in a subfolder relative to your application's entry assembly, then specifying a relative path should work:

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = "dreammusic\\DrmMTrack8.lite.mp3";
```

The problem with your code is the **leading backslash** (`\\dreammusic`), which makes your path an absolute (rooted) path and is resolved to something like `C:\\dreammusic\\DrmMTrack8.lite.mp3`.

Comment: I think the problem is located with the music being located relative to the executables path, not with being in the users special folders